# Blank screen after grub menu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, boot, grub

I just rebooted an Ubuntu Server 10.04. After choosing boot options in the grub menu, though, it just displays a black screen with the blinking white underscore in the upper-left corner.

The machine has had (hardware) trouble with networking before, but the problem remains after 10 minutes, so I don't think it's the problem now. Booting into recovery mode or using earlier kernels yields the same problem. This also happens if I boot from another hard-drive.

I haven't yet tried to boot from CD as the machine lacks a CD reader.

How should I diagnose the problem?

**Update**: My boot options are:

```
recordfail
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 567[redacted]
linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-29-generic root=UUID=567[redacted] ro quiet splash
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-29-generic
```

**Update**: Also, I cannot access the virtual terminals (ctrl+alt+Fn).

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the selected option ('e') going to the 'kernel' line and removing the 'quiet' and 'splash' options from the end if they are there, then continue the boot and see if you get a few more diagnostics to help you.

Comment: I tried to remove them, but the same thing happens. No additional information. I updated my post with the full boot options according to grub.

Comment: Bah, how evil. Trying my best to give other solutions than to reinstall grub2/grub... I see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/499220/comments/2 has a solution to this problem, when it was caused by a faulty clock. Perhaps try adding those two boot parameters "clocksource=hpet" and "notsc" to the kernel line and see if that works? If so, I'll update my answer above with the permanent solution.

Comment: Hmm... googling "clocksource=hpet" shows quite a lot of people with 'similar' issues being solved with this. I'm hopeful!

Comment: This unfortunately did not change anything, either.